# AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate methods not called

Tags: ios, swift, security, ssl, avkit

I'm trying to play an online live stream (.m3u8) securely. I am creating an `AVAsset` and assigning its delegate to a singleton that conforms to `AVAssetResourceLoader`. The problem is, the `delegate` methods are not called.

Code:

PlayerViewController:

```
let asset: AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset(url: url, options: ["AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey": headerFields])
    let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
    
    asset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(SSLAuthenticator.default, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
```

SSL Authenticator

```
func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForResponseTo authenticationChallenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge) -> Bool {
    print("0")
    return true
}

func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, didCancel authenticationChallenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge) {
    print("1")
}

func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, didCancel loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest) {
    print("2")
}

func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest) -> Bool {
    print("3")
    return true
}

func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForRenewalOfRequestedResource renewalRequest: AVAssetResourceRenewalRequest) -> Bool {
    print("4")
    return true
}
```

Does anyone know why the delegate methods are not being called?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Methods of `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` are getting called when AVPlayer don't know how to download the data. So for URL like `https://link_to_data.com` AVPlayer will download the data by itself. To force AVPlayer to use your delegate the URL should contain the unknown scheme, for example, `custom://link_to_data.com`. 
[Here is an excellent example of implementing that.](https://jaredsinclair.com/2016/09/03/implementing-avassetresourceload.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The example you provided does not explain how to handle authentication using AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate. My problem is that I need to pin the SSL certificate of my remote AVAsset before playing it.

Comment: When you are using `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` it's your responsibility to handle data loading. For example, for `mp3` file, you can use `URLSession` to download it and then send data to ResourceLoader. So it means authentication would be handled by some sort of `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate`. I don't have experience in SSL pinning so don't know how exactly it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the delegate instance needs to be kept in memory, in your case, you may try to store *SSLAuthenticator.default* in some global variable and then set it as a delegate.

```
gloabalObject = SSLAuthenticator.default
asset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(gloabalObject, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
```

Usually delegate methods wont be called if the delegate instance is destroyed before its methods are called.